# Making Refresh Token Request In Java With JWT through a stand alone application - Not a Web App

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-authentication, jwt

I have a question regarding getting Refresh Token for Google Analytics using JWT.

Please refer the below sample code which is working fine and i am able to get the Analytics object, using which i am able to access the Analytics data.

```
        GoogleCredential credentialGA = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("$#$@#$#$#$@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("$#$#$%$%$%$-privatekey.p12"))
                .build();
        this.analytics = new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credentialGA).setApplicationName("Demo App").build();
```

If i make a call to **credentialGA.getAccessToken()** it returns me a string. But making a call to        **credentialGA.getRefreshToken()**  it always returns me null.
Now as per the saying if i have to use this Analytics object for further calls, i need to have refresh token using which i can again create GoogleCredential object to get Analytics object.

So i created a JWT, after following the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount. This JWT is then to be used for making refresh token call. 
Example shared on this link explains how to make it possible through servlet/jsp/http.
https://code.google.com/p/gwdg-java/source/browse/src/java/com/google/iapsample/?r=a52c4e72381b1fc959053e3a1fc8c585ae2d7112

Is there any example code which may explain to achieve the same task of Refresh token call using JWT using Java Standalone app.

Thanks in advance.

regards,
Prathamesh

Code to generate JWT :

```
    private final static Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
private static KeyStore myStore = null;
private static FileInputStream in_cert = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;       
    try {
        in_cert = new FileInputStream(
                "D://Google Analytics//ClientLogin//Analytics//%#$%#$%$^%^%$&^%&$-privatekey.p12");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        myStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        myStore.load(in_cert, "notasecret".toCharArray());

        Enumeration<String> aliases = myStore.aliases();
        String alias = "";       
        Enumeration objEnumeration = myStore.aliases();
        while (objEnumeration.hasMoreElements() == true) {
            alias = (String) objEnumeration.nextElement();

            privateKey = (PrivateKey) myStore.getKey(alias,
                    "notasecret".toCharArray());
            if(privateKey != null){
            System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY:" + privateKey.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObject header = new JsonObject();
    header.addProperty("alg", "RS256");
    header.addProperty("typ", "JWT");
    String headerStr = header.toString();

    JsonObject claim = new JsonObject();
    claim.addProperty("iss", "%^@%@^%$%@developer.gserviceaccount.com");
    claim.addProperty("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.readonly");
    claim.addProperty("aud", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    claim.addProperty("exp", "1384497516");
    claim.addProperty("iat", "1384597516");     
    String claimStr = claim.toString();

    try {

        byte[] headerArr = headerStr.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
        System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(headerArr));
        byte[] claimArr = claimStr.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
        System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(claimArr));
        String inputStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(headerArr) + "." + Base64.encodeBase64String(claimArr);         
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(inputStr.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This JWT string is then copied and used in another programmer to request for Refresh token as shown below:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("<link i have posted in the comment>");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type",
                "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assertion",
                "<JWT Calculated earlier>"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
                String key = line.substring(5);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Link mentioned in the code : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need for a successful API call is an access token. For a service account, you get an access token by signing a JWT with a private key and sending it to accounts.google.com.

It looks like your code above should do this fine.

A refresh token is a different kettle of fish.  This is something that Google will supply your application with after an end-user has authorized your application for access to their data.  Similar to the private key above it can be used to get an access token that can then be used for subsequent API calls.

So simply put, for a service account use-case (which is what the code snippet shows) you should never need to see a refresh token at all.  What specifically are you looking to do?

Comment: I am looking for sample code which can give me an overview creating JWT and using this JWT to send a request for the refresh token. I tried doing the same. I was unable to get any sample to verify my efforts against. Unfortunately not enough documentation or sample from google too. If i try to run my code i am getting {
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}

Comment: What I am saying is that it is not possible to get a refresh token using a JWT.  Both private key + JWT and refresh tokens are ways to acquire an access token, which is ultimately what you need to make an API call.  What leads you to believe that you need a refresh token for your service account?  (I would highly recommend using the Google supplied Java client library to handle authorization rather than generating the underlying structures yourself)

Comment: Please pardon me if i am wrong...my basic requirement was to get the refresh token as documented in the OAuth 2.0 developer guide. If the above process is not required for getting refresh token then even after using it to get the access token does not yield any result but than to return error. If the same request is made to get access token its is still failing. Please help me out in understanding my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the question at the top you say that "the below sample code which is working fine and i am able to get the Analytics object, using which i am able to access the Analytics data."  I don't understand why you are trying to get an underlying refresh or access token if you already have code (using the recommended libraries) that works.  Can you give me a bit more detail on exactly what you are trying to achieve?  Or is that sample code is in fact rendering an error, can you paste in the exact error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the validity of the accessToken by calling the

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}
```

endpoint and make the JWT again and get the accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a litle late but I needed to implement my own JWT generation to access firebase cloud message, and notice in your code is missing this:

```
byte[] sig = signature.sign();
```

To correctly sign JWT.

Whole part:

```
jwt = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(headerStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) + "."
                    + Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(claimStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String inpSign = new String(jwt);
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(inpSign.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            byte[] sig = signature.sign();
            jwt = jwt + "."+ Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(sig);
```